# Ubuntu SDK: How can I see error logs for my ubuntu touch app?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I've built an ubuntu touch app, it works well on desktop, but when I install it on the device and try to launch, it crashes. Where can I find error logs or any other output that the app can give me to figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logs for your application can be found in the `~/.cache/upstart/` folder on your device.

I'd recommend to open/cat them using a remote connection (with `phablet-shell`)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can also install the **[LogViewer](https://launchpad.net/logviewer)** app from the store to see the logs with a graphical interface. The application provides the following features,

- Graphical interface for viewing logs
- Exporting logs to pastebin

[image]

Comment: Can you please include a link to the app store page or better yet a screen shot?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I added a screenshot of the logviewer app as you requested.